# Is there an easy way to convert a string into a websocket frame format?

Tags: java, websocket, java-websocket

So I set up a WebSocket in Java. To send messages, those messages have to be in a Frame format defined [here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455). I found a method some [really nice person](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1679439/haribabu-pasupathy) wrote in java, to convert a string into a frame.
But now i'm wondering is there a built-in way to do this? It seems kind of weird, that everybody who wants to use this API needs to implement the method him or herself.

Code (from [Haribabu Pasupathy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1679439/haribabu-pasupathy)):

```
public static byte[] convertStringToFrame(String message) {
        byte[] rawData = message.getBytes();

        int frameCount  = 0;
        byte[] frame = new byte[10];

        frame[0] = (byte) 129;

        if(rawData.length <= 125) {
            frame[1] = (byte) rawData.length;
            frameCount = 2;
        }
        else if (rawData.length >= 126 && rawData.length <= 65535) {
            frame[1] = (byte) 126;
            int len = rawData.length;
            frame[2] = (byte)((len >> 8 ) & (byte)255);
            frame[3] = (byte)(len & (byte)255);
            frameCount = 4;
        }
        else {
            frame[1] = (byte) 127;
            int len = rawData.length;
            frame[2] = (byte)((len >> 56 ) & (byte)255);
            frame[3] = (byte)((len >> 48 ) & (byte)255);
            frame[4] = (byte)((len >> 40 ) & (byte)255);
            frame[5] = (byte)((len >> 32 ) & (byte)255);
            frame[6] = (byte)((len >> 24 ) & (byte)255);
            frame[7] = (byte)((len >> 16 ) & (byte)255);
            frame[8] = (byte)((len >> 8 ) & (byte)255);
            frame[9] = (byte)(len & (byte)255);
            frameCount = 10;
        }

        int bLength = frameCount + rawData.length;

        byte[] reply = new byte[bLength];

        int bLim = 0;
        for(int i=0; i<frameCount;i++){
            reply[bLim] = frame[i];
            bLim++;
        }
        for(int i=0; i<rawData.length;i++){
            reply[bLim] = rawData[i];
            bLim++;
        }

        return reply;
    }
```

Comment: What did you find when you searched for "Java websocket client"?

Comment: @JimGarrison I found Spring. But why would there be now built in way for this. It seems like a pretty common use case to me.

Comment: Websocket is an RFC anyone can implement.  If it becomes ubiquitous then Oracle/OpenJDK ***may*** eventually include it. Until then, an Open Source library is the best you can do.  That's one of the main strengths of Open Source.  Look at how long it took for Java to incorporate the ideas from libraries like Joda Time into java.time.*.  I wouldn't hold my breath.  Find the O/S library that works for you and proceed.